# Remove redundant beautifulsoup html tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tree, xml-parsing

How can I remove "redundant" html tags inside a beautifulsoup object?

In the example of

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <div>
       <div>
        Close
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div style="width:80px">
      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button>
        Close
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

how can I remove redundant `<div>` tags (redundant, as in that they only add to the depth, but do not contain any addition information or attributes) to the following structure:

```
<html>
 <body>
       <div>
        Close
       </div>
     <div style="width:80px">
       <button>
        Close
       </button>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In terms of a graph-algorithm, I am trying to merge multiple nodes together within the beautifulsoup tree that do not contain stringts, nor attributes.

Comment: Just to make sure an answer is not too closely tailored to the sample html: you have one element with text (`<button>`) with one ancestor which has an attribute and another element with no such ancestor. But is it possible that a text element has two nested ancestors with attributes? Is it possible that an element with an attribute does not have a child with text?

Comment: Yes, it would be great to have a snippet which is as general as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a code-snippet that seems to do the job:

```
        for x in reversed(soup()):
            if not x.string and not x.attrs and len(x.findChildren(recursive=False)) <= 1:
                x.unwrap()
```

The `reversed` is needed, as otherwise empty tags are counted as siblings, blocking the unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to replace any divs without attributes (i.e. `div.attrs == {}`) with their children:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    if not div.attrs:
        div.unwrap()
```

Output of `print(soup.prettify())`:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <button>
   Close
  </button>
  <div style="width:80px">
   <button>
    Close
   </button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

For the updated example (see comment) it would be:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    if not div.attrs and div.div:
        div.unwrap()
```

i.e. remove div if it has no attributes and if it's followed by another div

Comment: thanks a lot! I just realized that my example case was not quite right and updated the question.. sry for the confusion